# Issue with changing a variable within a SetObject on C++

Tags: c++, sprite, game-boy-advance

I am creating a basic endless runner game for GBA, using notepad++. My running character is consisted of sprites which i need to automatically change at set intervals inside the main game loop, but i cannot seem to find a method which allows me to do this, my code below is very basic i know but i think the logic of it is sound and that it should work.I have four sprites which are changed by changing the run variable in intervals of 2.
Thanks for any help in advance.

```
//main game loop

while (true)
{
    const uint8_t currentKeys = REG_KEYINPUT;  

    frame += 1;

    if (frame == 4)
        run += 2;

    if (frame == 8)
        run += 2;

    if (frame == 12)
        run += 2;

    if (frame == 16)
        run += 2;

    if (frame == 20)
        run = 0;
        frame = 0;

    if (currentKeys != prevKeys )  
    {
        if ((currentKeys & KEY_UP) == 0)    //
        {
            velocityY = -6.0f;
        }
    }

        SetObject(0,
            ATTR0_SHAPE(2) | ATTR0_8BPP | ATTR0_REG | ATTR0_Y(20),
            ATTR1_SIZE(2) | ATTR1_X(120),
            ATTR2_ID8(run));

    prevKeys = currentKeys;
    Update_Physics();
    WaitVSync();
    UpdateObjects();
}
```

Comment: `frame` is always set to 0 (`frame = 0` is not part of the `if` statement and it therefore runs at each iteration).

Answer (score 3):

Is changing:

```
    if (frame == 20)
        run = 0;
        frame = 0;
```

to:

```
    if (frame == 20)
    {
        run = 0;
        frame = 0;
    }
```

enough to fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

this is simple mistake.

You should understand the scope of the if function. Pay attention to below code segment.

```
if (frame == 20)
      run = 0;
      frame = 0; //this statement is executes always as it is not in above if statements scope.
```

As this is in the main game loop, the value of `frame` is always eveliate to `0`. But your requirement would be to set `frame` to `0` if `frame == 20` only.

In order to achieve it, insert the `frame = 0;` statement in the the scope of `if (frame == 20)`.

```
if (frame == 20) {
    run = 0;
    frame = 0;
    //scope of if statement
}
```

scope of if statement -

if you have only one statement, to execute with if statement you can just specify the statement with if statement.

```
if(condition)
   statement;
```

but if you have more than one condition, you can use `{` and `}` to enclose all the statement and add those statements to if statements scope.

```
if(condition) {
  statement_1; // scope begind
  statement_2;
  statement_3;
  statement_*;
} // scope ends
```